# Android studio sharing all projects to github

Tags: android, git, android-studio, github

I am using Android Studio 3.0.1 when I tried to share my project to Github it gets successfully added to GitHub but when I check GitHub under that repository it added all the projects present in *C:\Users\USERNAME\AndroidStudioProjects*. How to allow Android Studio to only add the project which I am sharing instead of all.
[image: here is the screenshot]

inside the folder AndroidStudioProjects it adds all the android studio projects to github under a single repository when i tried to share one project.
I add project to github manually in android studio on clicking share project on github and when i click on share button it gets shared on github successfully but it adds all the projects from my projects folder.

Answer (score 0):

That means your local git repository is located here:

C:\Users\USERNAME\AndroidStudioProjects

There are different ways to add just one project to github.
If you are going to add an existing project, firstly, create a github project, create local git repository of your android studio project, then use git -> removes and add there a github link.

Comment: how to fix above problem?